# Can I use QtCreator to create Windows install for a Qt Windows Application?

Tags: qt-creator

I have a Qt Windows app (developed in QtCreator) that I'd like to create a windows install CD. Does QtCreator have a feature that makes this possible? Or do I have to use NSIS ? Please help.
- Nkumar

Comment: Inno Setup is the best for a quick implementation. Select New and simply follow the wizard dialog.

Answer (score 3):

You can also check out the [Qt Installer framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtinstallerframework-1.4/index.html), this lets you make cross-platform installers.

Comment: how do I use Qt Installer Framework to create a Qt Application Installer or Deployment.?

Answer (score 2):

Qt Creator doesn't do installers. NSIS or [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) are probably your best bets here.

Answer (score 1):

For windows you can use one of these:

1. http://izpack.org/
2. http://nsis.sourceforge.net

Prepare your installer and then burn in to CD. You can also add an autorun.inf file to make the installer start automagically :) Although i heard that microsoft is planing to disable the autorun feature due to security reasons.

If you're developing cross-platform versions then each linux distribution has it's own installation systems.

For example:

Debian,Ubuntu ... - *.deb
Redhat,openSuse, .. - *.rpm